# The JQuery window object scroll top function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started learning javascript and jQuery, and I have a question regarding the window object `$(window)`.  I have this code, which make a div stick to the top of the screen when it is scrolled to top.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $("#sticky-anchor").offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
    });
});
```

what i don't understand is that if the entire screen is the window, then when will the window_top > div_top?

Comment: When the `div` is scrolled off the screen. It is above the `window_top`

Comment: so when it is off screen its value is less? hence the window_top > div_top operation?

Comment: Sorry, it's the opposite, that will be true, as long as the `div` hasn't been scrolled up off the page

Answer (score 1):

**The top property returns the topmost browser window of the current window.**

`top` is useful both when you're dealing with frames and when dealing with windows which have been opened by other pages.

[image: Topmost of current window]

the place in Red will be always considered as `top`! If you scroll page, whichever part of your page in that **RED area**, that part is now at `window.top`.

> So, if your `DIV` is above that `top`, `window_top > div_top` returns
>   `true` otherwise else part gets executed!

Comment: wait. the code is opposite.  When my div is above that `top`, `window_top > div_top` return true, the code `$('#sticky').addClass('stick')` execute. so the div with id sticky will have class stick added to it.

Comment: really? alright! then you can revert the action from `if` to `else` part! that is it! and apologize for that.. will edit the answer!

Comment: so does this mean that the `window_top` return a value that is greater than the value when a div is offset? this is where it's stripping me off.  if the code was `window_top < div_top` then i wouldn't have any problem, but its opposite.  I'm confuse

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for trying to help me with my question.  After doing several console.log() in attempt to try and figure out the logic behind the code.  I was able to figure it out.  the `var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();` is initially 0 when the page load and no scrolling is done.  when the page is being scrolled, the value increases. The initial value of `var div_top = $("#sticky-anchor").offset().top;` is the height from the `<div id="sticky">` to the top.  The statement `if (window_top > div_top)` return true when the sticky div offset the top.